# estoy trabajando en colab y tengo el siguiente error: "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable"

Tags: python, redes-neuronales

estoy trabajando con mnist y en el momento de crear y configurar los minibatches me da error, al consultar sobre el error encontre que no es la forma adecuada de determinar una funcion, por otro lado que es problema de [] por (),    pero como se ve en el error la raiz proviene de la 4 linea  que esta asociada a la 4 linea del bloque enterior donde de decretan las variables

Adjunto el codigo:

```
def accuracy(x_data, y_data, mb_size=64):
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(create_minibatches(mb_size, x_data, y_data)):
        scores2, z1, a1 = scores(x.T, parameters, relu)
        y_hat, cost = x_entropy(scores2, y, batch_size=len(x))
        
        correct += np.sum(np.argmax(y_hat, axis=0) == y.squeeze())
        total += y_hat.shape[1]
    return correct/total

    
    def train(epochs, parameters, mb_size=64, learning_rate = 1e-3):
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            for i, (x, y) in enumerate(create_minibatches(mb_size, x_train, y_train)):
                ***scores2, z1, a1 = scores(x.T, parameters=parameters, activation_fcn=relu)***
                y_hat, cost = x_entropy(scores2, y, batch_size=len(x))
                grads = backward(y_hat, x, y, z1, a1, scores2, parameters, batch_size=len(x))
                
                parameters['W1'] = parameters['W1'] - learning_rate*grads['w1']
                parameters['b1'] = parameters['b1'] - learning_rate*grads['b1']
                parameters['b2'] = parameters['b2'] - learning_rate*grads['b2']
                parameters['W2'] = parameters['W2'] - learning_rate*grads['W2']
                
            print(f'costo es: {cost}, y accuracy: {accuracy(x_val, y_val, mb_size)}')
        return parameters
    
    mb_size = 512
    learning_rate = 1e-2
    epochs = 20
    ***parameters = train(epochs=epochs, parameters=parameters, mb_size=mb_size, learning_rate=learning_rate)***
```

Adjunto el mensaje de error completo:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-32-fb391274b51e> in <cell line: 4>()
        2 learning_rate = 1e-2
        3 epochs = 20
----> 4 parameters = train(epochs=epochs, parameters=parameters, mb_size=mb_size, learning_rate=learning_rate)

<ipython-input-31-621974be0fc6> in train(epochs, parameters, mb_size, learning_rate)
        2     for epoch in range(epochs):
        3         for i, (x, y) in enumerate(create_minibatches(mb_size, x_train, y_train)):
----> 4             scores2, z1, a1 = scores(x.T, parameters=parameters, activation_fcn=relu)
        5             y_hat, cost = x_entropy(scores2, y, batch_size=len(x))
        6             grads = backward(y_hat, x, y, z1, a1, scores2, parameters, batch_size=len(x))
        
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: Hola Juan, pues parece que `scores` (en tu código no aparece definida, por lo que no se de donde viene ni que debería ser) es un array de NumPy cuando claramente tu esperas que sea un callable, seguramente una función. Puedes obtener el mismo error con `import numpy as np;scores = np.array([]); scores()` Es posible que en algún punto anterior el identificador global `scores` haya sido reasignada a un array de numpy por error.

Comment: si, esta definida mas arriba, de hecho llamo a "scores.shape" y me devuelve "(10, 64)" (como es debido)

Comment: Un array de NumPy no es callable, no lo puedes llamar como si fuera una función. Esta linea `scores2, z1, a1 = scores(x.T, parameters=parameters, activation_fcn=relu)` es ilegal, puedes indizar sobre un array (para eso se usan los `[]` que mencionas) o llamar a alguno de sus métodos/obtener atributos de instancia (como `shape`), pero no llamarlo. Si aclaras que esperas que pase en esa linea así como los datos y tipos `scores` y los "parametros" que intentas pasarle (`x.T`, `parameters`,  `relu`) a lo mejor podemos ayudar.

Comment: lo que intento hacer es calcular los scores de entrenamiento, dejo el enlace del video con el que estoy trabajando: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQGolGJZz80&list=PLWzLQn_hxe6ZlC9-YMt3nN0Eo-ZpOJuXd&index=18

Comment: a partir del minuto 8 del video se genera el codigo

Comment: Hola Juan, `scores` es una función, la define en el video anterior en https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5HJKWL2i08&list=PLWzLQn_hxe6ZlC9-YMt3nN0Eo-ZpOJuXd&t=1582s  (la llama inicialmente `linear_pass` pero luego la renombra a `scores`. Posteriormente usa también el identificador `scores` como nombre del array lo cual es una pésima idea porque con ello ensombrece a la `funcion` con el mismo nombre y causa tu confusión y error...

Comment: @FJSevilla le coloque el nombre "linear_pass" nuevamente para verificar lo que me indicas, pero sigue arrojando el mismo error. Ahora tengo definidas "scores2" y "linear_pass", y aun asi persiste numpy.ndarray

Comment: Debes renombrar la funcion y cambiar el nombre en todos los casos donde se use, incluida logicmante la linea del error: `scores2, z1, a1 = linear_pass(x.T, parameters=parameters, activation_fcn=relu)`. Si usas un notebook recuerda reejecutar todas las celdas para actualizar todo. No he revisado los videos por completo, asegurate que no se usa `linear_pass` como identificador de otra cosa aparte de para nombrar la función...

Comment: si, claro... renombre y cambie todos los casos y ejecute el notebook desde el principio. no, no usa linear_pass para ninguna otra cosa

Comment: Si pudieras compartir todo el código tal y como lo tienes seria mas fácil indicar exactamente donde esta el problema.Si no puedes hacerlo editando la pregunta (porque sea muy largo) puedes subir el notebook  a la nube, github, etc y compartir el enlace.El autor del video tiene que corregir el problema del sombreado de la variable en alguna parte (no he tenido tiempo de ver completos ambos videos) porque al final después de corregir los otros problemas (como el renombrado de scores2) el código funciona, por lo que en algún momento lo corrige y  te los has saltado o el se ha olvidado de contarlo

Comment: dejo el git de los archivos: https://github.com/JuanManuelSanchez2022/mnist , el archivo en cuestion es "red_neuronal1.ipynb"

Comment: Hola Juan, he creado una respuesta que basicamente es lo que hemos estado hablando. El error es el comentado, solo que al intentar corregirlo has renombrado todas las apariciones de scores por linear_pass, solo debes renombrar las llamadas a la función no el array. Como tienes un notebook y aquí se pierde la estructura me he tomado la libertad de hacer una PR a tu repo de github con los cambios, que es básicamente lo que explico en la respuesta, pero asi no pierdes el notebook y evitamos confusiones.

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que en la linea:

```
scores2, z1, a1 = scores(x.T, parameters=parameters, activation_fcn=relu)
```

se esta intentando llamar a `scores`, que es un array de NumPy, y por tanto es un objeto no llamable.

Aunque se define `scores` como una función previamente:

```
def scores(x, parameters, activation_fcn):

    #¤ x tiene la forma (#pixeles, num samples)

    z1 = parameters['W1'] @ x + parameters['b1']
    a1 = activation_fcn(z1) # devuel fcn. de activa.
    z2 = parameters['W2'] @ a1 + parameters['b2']

    return z2, z1, a1
```

el problema viene cuando se hace a continuación:

```
scores, z1, a1 = scores(x_train[:64].T, parameters, relu)
```

a partir de este momento el identificador/variable `scores` deja de ser una función para ser el primer elemento de la salida de la función, `z2`, es decir un array de NumPy. En adelante, la función a la que `scores` hacia referencia deja de ser accesible porque su identificador ahora apunta a otro objeto.

Esto es un error del autor del tutorial, que aunque corregirá después en algún momento (porque al final su código funciona) no deja de ser tremendamente confuso y termina causando errores como en tu caso.

La solución es simplemente renombrar la función o renombrar la variable asociada a su salida para que no sean la misma:

```
def linear_pass(x, parameters, activation_fcn):

    #¤ x tiene la forma (#pixeles, num samples)

    z1 = parameters['W1'] @ x + parameters['b1']
    a1 = activation_fcn(z1) # devuel fcn. de activa.
    z2 = parameters['W2'] @ a1 + parameters['b2']

    return z2, z1, a1
```

cambiando el nombre en el resto de sitios donde se llama:

```
scores, z1, a1 = linear_pass(x_train[:64].T, parameters, relu)
```

---

```
def accuracy(x_data, y_data, mb_size=64):
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(create_minibatches(mb_size, x_data, y_data)):
        scores2, z1, a1 = linear_pass(x.T, parameters, relu)
        y_hat, cost = x_entropy(scores2, y, batch_size=len(x))

        correct += np.sum(np.argmax(y_hat, axis=0) == y.squeeze())
        total += y_hat.shape[1]
    return correct/total
```

---

```
def train(epochs, parameters, mb_size=64, learning_rate = 1e-3):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for i, (x, y) in enumerate(create_minibatches(mb_size, x_train, y_train)):
            scores2, z1, a1 = linear_pass(x.T, parameters=parameters, activation_fcn=relu)
            y_hat, cost = x_entropy(scores2, y, batch_size=len(x))
            grads = backward(y_hat, x, y, z1, a1, scores2, parameters, batch_size=len(x))

            parameters['W1'] = parameters['W1'] - learning_rate*grads['w1']
            parameters['b1'] = parameters['b1'] - learning_rate*grads['b1']
            parameters['b2'] = parameters['b2'] - learning_rate*grads['b2']
            parameters['W2'] = parameters['W2'] - learning_rate*grads['W2']

        print(f'costo es: {cost}, y accuracy: {accuracy(x_val, y_val, mb_size)}')
    return parameters
```

---

```
def predict(x):
    scores2, _, _ = linear_pass(x, parameters, relu)
    return np.argmax(scores2)
```

Dejando el resto igual.

Comment: funcionando!!!! muchisimas graciasss!!!! genio...